# drbd master/master without cluster FS

Tags: drbd

I have planed to use master-slave setup and make nightly backups (just coping data) from slave node to 3rd node.

As I understand in master-slave mode it is impossible to read data from slave node? So the question is... what will happened if I will use master-master setup without cluster fs, and will use one of master just as read-only to make backups of it and writes will occur only to second master.

On top of setup will be NFS exports and iSCSI.

Will it work? Maybe there will be some problems...?

Comment: If you are not using a cluster fs you can read from the secondary server, but only from drdb and not mount a filesystem, so you could or example use dd to copy the bits but that's probably not what you want. It would be probably easier to just create a master/master setup and write only to one node, but use the second node for backups.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple task like backup, I recomment [csync2](http://oss.linbit.com/csync2/).

```
Csync2 is a cluster synchronization tool. It can be used to keep files on
multiple hosts in a cluster in sync. Csync2 can handle complex setups with
much more than just 2 hosts, handle file deletions and can detect conflicts.
```